# Change UpdateSourceTrigger of Custom UserControl according to User's use

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

I have the following custom user control:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock  x:Name="Placeholder_PART" Background="White" Text="{Binding Placeholder, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" Foreground="Gray" Margin="4"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="Textbox_PART" Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay,  RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" Background="Transparent" TextChanged="txt_TextChanged"/>
</Grid>
```

I'm using this usercontrol like this:

```
<S:TextBoxWithPlaceHolder FontSize="25" FontFamily="David" Width="130" Text="{Binding World2, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Placeholder="{Binding World, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="40" />
```

the binding is fired only when i lose focus even tough i set it to propertychanged, i know that it's because the custom user control's UpdateSourceTrigger is default.

How can i make the UpdateSourceTrigger of the custom user control changes according to the user UpdateSourceTrigger(in this case property changes)
like simple textbox binding, or any element?

Answer (score 1):

Your `TextBoxWithPlaceHolder.Text` will update the source upon `PropertyChanged`, however the `TextBox` inside it will only update `TextBoxWithPlaceHolder.Text` property upon `LostFocus` (the default for `TextBox`). So you should modify the binding on `TextBox.Text` and set `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this without setting the `UpdateSourceTrigger` property of the binding of the `TextBox` that you define inside the `UserControl` to `PropertyChanged`.

The binding of the `Text` property of the `TextBoxWithPlaceHolder` control is not the same as the binding of the `TextBox` control that is defined inside the control. These are two separate `Binding` objects, defined and created in different classes, with their own separate `UpdateSourceTrigger` properties.

In other words the consumer of the `TextBoxWithPlaceHolder` control doesn't control the `UpdateSourceTrigger` of the `TextBox` that is part of the (internal logic of the) control itself. Only you as a control author controls this.

If you really want the consumer to be able to change the `UpdateSourceTrigger` of the `TextBox`, you could add a dependency property to the `TextBoxWithPlaceHolder` control and register a callback that creates a new binding and sets the `UpdateSourceTrigger` property of the new binding to the appropriate value.